# Composer cannot delete .editorconfig

Tags: composer

I'm trying to install a third-party library in Drupal 8 by doing 'composer update'. I get this:

[image]

I have made it seemingly impossible for it not to be able to delete .editorconfig:

[image]

But I still get the same error. What should I try next?

Comment: `chown` that file to your own username, or whatever username you run composer as?

Comment: I did -- I run as administrator.

Comment: Out of frustration, I ran composer as root (yeah, I know, I shouldn't do that) and it ran successfully. I still figure why it won't complete as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

From https://superuser.com/questions/373115/why-cant-i-delete-a-file-where-i-have-group-write-permissions-on

- File deletion is based on directory perms, not file perms (*).

That said, check the directory `/var/www/html/drupal_2020` permissions.